# Where's my mistake ? $\int_{0}^{4\pi}\frac{1}{5+4cos(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate
$$\int_{0}^{4\pi}\frac{1}{5+4cos(x)}dx$$

I noted $u=tan(x/2)$ and I got $\int_{0}^{4\pi}\frac{2}{u^{2}+3^2}du=\frac{2}{3}arctan\frac{tan\frac{x}{2}}{3}$ but and I don't know what mistake I make because when I replace x with $4pi$ and $0$ I get the response $\frac{2}{3}(0-0)=0$ and the right answer is $\frac{4\pi}{3}$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You cannot use this substitution here without spliting the integral up since both borders of integration equal $0$ after the substitution. You need to take care of the periodicity (and sigularity) of the tangent function.

Comment: You have to be careful with that substitution, because $\tan \frac{\pi} {2} $ is a singularity there. So maybe try to split into four intervals like $0$ to $\pi$ and so on.

Comment: ,$\tan y$ is not continuous hence not differentiable at $\dfrac\pi2$

Comment: God, I completely forgot about that.Thank you for your answers:)

Comment: Any chance you're familiar with complex variables?

Comment: No, unfortunately. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the cosine function is an even function, so we can proceed as follows (pic.).

[image: Solution]

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Your Welcome!!!

Comment: @user219199 Please do not use images as main content of a post. Instead, write your answers (and questions!) in MathJax. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can find a quick tutorial :)

Comment: OK Sir, I'll do.Thank you!!!

Comment: Good work, nice answer, but sadly I had to give it a downvote because it was all done as an image. Math.SE is a great place to learn how to use MathJax, which will give you a massive headstart in learning LaTeX. Hope you learn MathJax and continue to contribute.

Comment: I'm a beginner, I;ll try Sir. Thank You!!!

Comment: @JonathanZ Sir as per your advice I have posted my answer (for a question before an hour) using MathJax. Thank you